# How to properly add view programatically?

Tags: java, android, layout, view, addition

I know that this topic is nothing new, but I really got stuck with this and tried a lot of answers and still I can't make it clear what and where should I write and use.

I have this layout file *settings.xml*

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    ...

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pass"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pass_del"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:text="Удалить пароль"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
   ...
</LinearLayout>
```

I have `TextView passdel` that I want to add programmatically. Its `onCreate` description is `passdel=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.pass_del);`

And I have these methods

```
public void onPasSet() {
        pass.setText("Сменить пароль"); 
        ((LinearLayout)passdel.getParent()).addView(passdel);
    }
    public void onPasDel() {
        pass.setText("Установить пароль"); 
        ((LinearLayout)passdel.getParent()).removeView(passdel); 
    }
```

`onPasDel` is working well. 
I guess Java takes current layout. So when I remove `View`, it's on this layout. And when I try to add this `View`, Java tries to find this view on current layout, but it's removed, so ..nullpointerexception. How should I write all `addView` stuff properly? How to point on the needed layout?

Comment: how would you expect `((LinearLayout)passdel.getParent()).addView(passdel);` to work? if you are adding `passdel` somewhere, it is probably because it does not have a parent, and therefore `getParent` cannot return anything but null. you should refer to the layout directly, by giving it an id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need to remove/add this `View`? If I understood the goal of this component correctly, the best way will be just to hide/show it:

```
 passdel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 passdel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Of course, after you've removed `passdel` from `ViewGroup`, it has no parents anymore, so you'll get `NPE` while trying to call `onPasSet()` after `onPasDel()`

Comment: I decided not to use setVisibility, because it just makes my views invisible and the blank space of these views just stays empty. I haven't found a way to remove this blank space, so removing and adding views dynamically seemed for me the best way. P.S I'm a newbie

Comment: @anindis No, from the docs description of `View.GONE`: This view is invisible, and **it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.**

Comment: oh. Thank you. Somehow I didn't come across to GONE. Thought there's only VISIBLE and INVISIBLE. And I didn't notice that you wrote GONE. Sorry. Shame on me

Answer (score 0):

As you suggested, `getParent()` won't work intil `TextView` is not instantiated.
You should get Layout in different way.
You can do it by `findViewById(R.id.layout.id)`.

Example: 
In XML:

```
<LinearLayout
...
android:id="@+id/my_layout">
...
```

In Activity:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_layout);
ll.addView(myView);
```